# Plotting ax.bar_label on sns does not iterate through hue appropriately

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have this table

```
print(tmp.head())

  tumor_type tumor_or_normal           call  size    cancer_n     %
0        ACC           Tumor  Amplification     2    ACC\nn=5  40.0
1        ACC           Tumor       Deletion     1    ACC\nn=5  20.0
2        ACC           Tumor        Diploid     2    ACC\nn=5  40.0
3       BLCA           Tumor  Amplification     3  BLCA\nn=10  30.0
4       BLCA           Tumor       Deletion     1  BLCA\nn=10  10.0
```

for which I am trying to add the size column values as bar labels:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20,8))
palette = {'Amplification': 'red', 'Deletion': 'blue', 'Diploid': 'grey'}
ax = sns.barplot(x ="cancer_n", y = '%', data = tmp, hue = "call", palette=palette, alpha=0.7)
for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container, labels=tmp['size'])
plt.show()
```

This uses the correct numbers but labels the bars incorrectly (labelling the first bar of each x-axis label instead of each bar of hue variable)

[See here for the plot and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcvLV.png)

How can I correct this?

Comment: The easiest would be leaving out the `labels=` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you give the whole `size` column for each hue. You need to provide the `size` values for 'Amplification', 'Deletion', and 'Diploid' separately.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20,8))
palette = {'Amplification': 'red', 'Deletion': 'blue', 'Diploid': 'grey'}
ax = sns.barplot(x ="cancer_n", y = '%', data = tmp, hue = "call", palette=palette, alpha=0.7)
for container in ax.containers:
    tmp_hue = tmp.loc[tmp['call']==container.get_label()]
    ax.bar_label(container, labels=tmp_hue['size'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: @JohanC Wouldn't leaving out labels only show the y-axis value (i.e. percentage) but OP wants to show a different column's value (i.e. size) on each bar?

Comment: In that case, it would be recommended to explicitly sort the dataframe.